# How to use another version of an assembly in a DLL, if App use an older version

Tags: c#, .net, version, .net-assembly

I developed a plugin (WPF DLL) for an application (not my application). My plugin uses Newtonsoft.Json and Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit. All was working fine. The new version of the application comes now with older versions of these two DLLs.
After many search and tries I changed the config file of the application like this:

original

```xml
    ...
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    ...
```

new

```xml
    ...
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
        <codeBase version="12.0.0.0" href="custom\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit" publicKeyToken="3e4669d2f30244f4" culture="neutral" />
        <codeBase version="4.0.0.0" href="custom\Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    ...
```

Now the plugin is working again. But I would like, if possible, not to change the config file of the app.

Is there any other possibility than this? Thank you.